# Update the record in all csv file by php

Tags: php

There are 50 csv files. each csv file have the same column's name. some content in the column are the same, some don't.

```
eg：test1.csv,  example1.csv, hello.csv,  world.csv.......test70.csv.
```

now, i want to make a change to two column's content.

a, all csv files have a column named `qty`.  whose rows content are all `0`. now, i want to change it into `888`

b, all csv files have a column named `img`. whose rows content are all

```
 upload/img1.jpg
 upload/img2.jpg
 upload/img3.jpg
 upload/img01.jpg
 upload/img14.jpg
 upload/img01.jpg
.......
```

If i open each csv file then do a search and replace. i fell it too bored.

Thank you in advance.

the csv file as the following:

http://phplist.xxmn.com/csv.jpg

i want to delete `Upload` in the image column, change 0 to 888 in the qty column.

i using the file `change.php` to update the record. 
the code:

```
<?php
$dir    = getcwd();
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.','change.php'));
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $new_content = '';
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            //var_dump($data);
           $data[2]=888; 
            $new_content .= implode(',', $data);
            //var_dump($new_content);
        }
       file_put_contents($file, $new_content);
        echo 'down';
    }
}

?>
```

the code doesn't work how to correct it . thank u

the csv file. 
http://phplist.xxmn.com/women.csv

Comment: What do you want to do to the `img` column values? What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Check out [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for reading from a CSV file.

Comment: if there is one csv file, i know how to read it. but there are 50 csv files. i don't know how to read them at the same time. i know i should put those name into an array, but i don't know how to write the loop

Comment: [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) will give you the list of files in a directory as an array.

Comment: i am stucked again. i have update the question. expect you can help me thank you

Comment: Dude. Do yourself a favor - use a database!

Comment: If any of those columns are surrounded by delimiters such as `"` to handle embedded commas, you'll need to handle that too. Also, you need line feeds between lines. Use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write to a new file.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to import that csv files to some table in mysql, do required changes using update query and export it back to csv. You don't need to headache about php codes :)

Comment: it's a good way. but i am a new learner of php. could you give me more  details to how to import that csv files to some table in mysql,  thank you

Comment: did i create a new database and create a table, which  columns are the same as the csv files columns? am i right?

Comment: You can also use [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) from the MySQL shell or a SQL command script to directly import the files into tables, but I believe you must create the tables yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop for all files and inside this loop, another loop for all lines.
Modify your columns, write the new content, and you're done !

Use this PHP function to read CSV file : [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $new_content = '';
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if ($new_content != '') { // Skip 1st line (headers)
                $data[1] = 888; // qty columns is the second columns => index is 1
            }
            $new_content .= implode(',', $data) . "\r\n";
        }
        file_put_contents($file, $new_content);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am sorry, it shows Warning: file_put_contents(Women.csv) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied i

Comment: Then you don't have the rights to write in the directory. Change the rights of your directory (are you on linux? windows ? do you know chmod ?)

Comment: i want to update the image column at the same time with qty. how do i do?

Comment: $data[0] = 'here the new value';

Comment: Try to check if your directory is "Read Only" in directory's properties. Your PHP must have the permission to write in the directory.

Comment: my csv file are all wrong, it put all the content in the one cell

Comment: Then maybe your separator is not a comma `,` but another one, try `;` for instance... please don't ask me how :)

Comment: i put a csv file on my question. could you help me again, thank you

Comment: it's ok, there is one thing that i can't understand well. ($new_content != '') { // Skip 1st line (headers)  why this line can skip the 1st line. thank you

Comment: there still something wrong with the code. if your give a test to this csv http://phplist.xxmn.com/women.csv you will be find, the content are all disorderd

Answer (score 0):

Below is the exact solution (assuming that your php and mysql resides on the same server)

suppose your csv file is

```
"1";"Desserts";"1";"category/vcm_s_kf_repr_806x645_7.jpg"
"2";"Beverages";"1";"category/aagya.jpg"
"3";"apetizers";"1";"category/Koala.jpg"
"13";"Breakfasts";"1";"category/Lighthouse_2.jpg"
"5";"Vegeterian entries";"1";"category/Desert.jpg"
"6";"Naan and Breads";"1";"category/Lighthouse_1.jpg"
"7";"Mexican";"1";"category/vcm_s_kf_repr_832x624_2.jpg"
```

say you have files like 001.csv, 002.csv and so on 
make one table exactly with same field that are in csv files

```
CREATE TABLE  `sample` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`flag` INT NOT NULL ,
`path` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) ,
UNIQUE (
`id`
 )
```

Then run a code below according to your customization

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("csv");
//find the current working f=directory
$dir=getcwd();
foreach (glob("*.csv") as $key=>$val) {
    echo $sql="LOAD DATA INFILE '".$dir."//".$val."' INTO TABLE sample";
    //now fire your update query , as an example here i am trying to replace all jpg with gif 
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $update="UPDATE sample SET path=REPLACE( path, '.jpg', ',bmp' )";
    mysql_query($update);
    //delete the table for next csv
    echo $outfile="SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '" .$dir."/converted_".$val."' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
              LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
              FROM sample";
    mysql_query($outfile);
    $del="delete from smaple";
    mysql_query($del);

}
```

Comment: if you put all the csv files in a table, then export those csv file, there will be only one csv file. i want to get import 50 csv files. export 50 csv files.

Comment: go through the code carefully, i have created new csv file inside each loop